# Frequency response measurement of power converter - Why is the injection point across the resistor?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, control-system, bode-plot, frequency-response

[image]

The standard procedure of measuring the frequency response of a buck converter is to inject a small voltage across a small resistor Rt as shown below. (Ref @[4:40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHCQ0GDlw6Q))

1. Why do we apply the input voltage across the Rt resistor and not at Point A?
2. We call the voltage at Point A as Vinput while plotting bode plot- even though, the voltage at Point A need not be the same voltage as applied by frequency analyzer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we apply the input voltage across the Rt resistor and not at Point A?

We use the open loop transfer function for stability analysis, don't we? So we need to break to loop. The idea is to break the loop from point B (or A assuming Rt is negligibly lower than R1) and apply a voltage externally, say V<sub>X</sub>. Then the converter will adjust the output across the load to V<sub>X</sub>. And if we add some disturbance to V<sub>X</sub> we can see the response of the converter to this disturbance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbu5S3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we attach probes to output and point B we can take measurements and generate bode plots.

In your case, you can break the loop from point A (or simply, remove Rt) and apply DC+AC (AC with offset). It's possible. But note that you want V<sub>X</sub> (DC offset) to be equal to the nominal output voltage of the converter. Because you also don't want to affect the overall performance of the converter while it's running at idle, or fully loaded, etc. Now if you have an analyser that is able to generate DC+AC reference signal then it'd be possible to break the loop from A and apply reference voltage and take measurements. But today's analysers generate AC (e.g. 1 Hz to 1 MHz). So all we can do is to "bind" the disturbance signal with a transformer (to isolate the analyser from DC conditions) to the DC output which is already available:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frZlEa.png)</sup>

<sup>NOTE: The configuration above assumes the response in the analyser is set to \$\mathrm{T(j\omega) = V_{CH1}(j\omega)/V_{CH2}(j\omega)}\$.</sup>

Without Rt, the injection transformer's secondary impedance (which varies with frequency during sweep) will be a part of the network and lead to false measurements because the output won't be the nominal value. So if we terminate it with a low enough resistance (10R is quite common) its effect on stability will be reduced to almost zero. Also 10R has almost no effect on output voltage given it's negligibly lower than R1 (e.g. 10R vs 33k). So it can be kept as a part of the circuit even if the injection transformer has been removed *(Thanks for the addition, Mr. Basso)*. Plus, point A (after Rt) can be used for remote sensing applications (along with another 10R placed in series with the output GND).

> We call the voltage at Point A as Vinput while plotting bode plot- even though, the voltage at Point A need not be the same voltage as applied by frequency analyzer.

It isn't. It includes the injection signal and a portion of ripple (response of the converter) but it doesn't matter because you attach the probes to both ends and the analyser compares these signal for gain and phase measurements.

Comment: As a side comment, the resistance is also there to ensure dc loop continuity without the transformer in place. I mean when you remove the transformer, there is no risk of loosing regulation since the loop is always closed with the resistance. It is good practice when laying out the prototype PCB to include this resistance with two associated pins so that you won't have to cut traces later on which can be a pain with very compact designs. My 2-Euro cent contribution to your good reply Rohat : )